# use XSLT to filter empty elements from XML

Tags: xml, xslt

that input xml has following structure:

```
 <EagleML>  
    <referenceTransaction>
        <rating>
            <effectiveDate>2012-12-14</effectiveDate>
            <ratingDataModel>
                <ratingChar1>TH_45</ratingChar1>
            </ratingDataModel>
        </rating>
    </referenceTransaction>
    <referenceTransaction>
        <rating>
            <effectiveDate>2012-12-14</effectiveDate>
            <ratingDataModel>
                <ratingChar1>WL_CONCERN</ratingChar1>
            </ratingDataModel>
        </rating>
    </referenceTransaction>
    <referenceTransaction>
        <rating>
            <effectiveDate></effectiveDate>
            <ratingDataModel>
                <ratingChar1>WL_CONCERN</ratingChar1>
            </ratingDataModel>
        </rating>
    </referenceTransaction>
</EagleML>
```

On the output, I need to use XSLT to get XML filtered by element referenceTransaction.
Leave those referenceTransaction nodes,
which contain the non-empty effectiveDate node and the value of the ratingChar1 node starts on WL.
Example output:

```
<EagleML>
    <referenceTransaction>
        <rating>
            <effectiveDate>2012-12-14</effectiveDate>
            <ratingDataModel>
                <ratingChar1>WL_CONCERN</ratingChar1>
            </ratingDataModel>
        </rating>
    </referenceTransaction>
</EagleML>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm not sure what's the question and where's the problem? You could check this article to help you out! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required expression

> element referenceTransaction. Leave those referenceTransaction nodes, which contain the non-empty effectiveDate node and the value of the ratingChar1 node starts on WL.

can be expressed in XPath as

```
normalize-space(rating/effectiveDate) != '' and starts-with(rating/ratingDataModel/ratingChar1,'WL')
```

Using [DeMorgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) this could be inverted to

```
normalize-space(rating/effectiveDate) = '' or not(starts-with(rating/ratingDataModel/ratingChar1,'WL'))
```

to match all `referenceTransaction` elements you want to be removed. This expression could then be used in a predicate of an empty template.

Overall the *identity template* copies all nodes and the empty template matches more specifically those elements you want to have removed.

The whole stylesheet could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity template -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- empty template with predicate -->
<xsl:template match="referenceTransaction[normalize-space(rating/effectiveDate) = '' or not(starts-with(rating/ratingDataModel/ratingChar1,'WL'))]">
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 for a good answer. Personal opinion/preference: I think `not(normalize-space(rating/effectiveDate))` reads better than `normalize-space(rating/effectiveDate) = ''`.